# Attempting binary serialization of a C# data class, can't modify until return call has finished executing. Why?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to create a visual novel engine. I have a data class containing information such as the position in the script. Right now it's very simple, just

```
[Serializable]
public class DataContainer
{
    private List<string> stackStringList = new List<string>();

    public int ScriptPosition { get; set; }
    public List<string> StackStringList
    {
        get { return stackStringList; }
        set { this.stackStringList = value; }
    }
}
```

I then have a class to perform the save and load functions,

```
class SaveAndLoad
    {
        public static void SerializeWithBinaryFormatter(DataContainer data, string fileName)
        {
            Stream streamOut = File.OpenWrite(fileName);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(streamOut, data);
            streamOut.Close();
        }
        public static object DeserializeWithBinaryFormatter(string fileName)
        {
            Stream streamIn = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            DataContainer obj = (DataContainer)formatter.Deserialize(streamIn);
            streamIn.Close();
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Everything saves/loads sort of fine, but when I try to use the ScriptPosition property of the recently deserialized data container, it just returns the int default, 0, and I have to do it after the call to return obj has finished executing.

Inserting Console.Write methods before and after shows that, if I had previously saved ScriptPosition as, say, 3, it will indeed be three after the return obj line executes, but not inbetween the return line and the DataContainer obj = (DataContainer)formatter.Deserialize(streamIn); line.

What I would like to do is instead

```
public static object DeserializeWithBinaryFormatter(string fileName)
        {
            Stream streamIn = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            DataContainer obj = (DataContainer)formatter.Deserialize(streamIn);
            // Do stuff with obj.ScriptPosition here
            streamIn.Close();
            return obj;
        }
```

I have got around this by just calling the relevant functions after I call DeserializeWithBinaryFormatter, however I can't see why obj.ScriptPosition would return 0, whereas returning the same obj reference into test and calling test.ScriptPosition would return what I had previously saved.

Comment: There's no good reason why `ScriptPosition` would behave magically - when does it return 0, and when does it magically return something non-zero? But more importantly, and I cannot say this strongly enough: **do not use `BinaryFormatter` here**. It is going to bite you - hard. It is *not* intended for this. Just about *any other serializer* would be more appropriate here. Except maybe `SoapFormatter` or `NetDataContractSerializer`, which share a position in the "don't use this" league

Comment: Could you explain why? I was having trouble getting any kind of serialization to work, and this just happened to be the first one that gave me the right result. I didn't pick it for any particular reason.

Comment: certainly! (I can talk about serialization for hours...) BinaryFormatter embeds too much type metadata: fully qualified type and assembly names (including version) and field names (not property names). Any refactor *whatsoever*, and your data will probably never load again. I strongly recommend contract-based serializers; json or XML for text - for binary protobuf-net is worth a look (I'm biased,  though).  I have answered far too many "by data doesn't load any more; why? questions to recommend BF. It is also framework and platform specific. It won't work *anywhere else*...